# Java Spring Boot Setting/Retrieving/Displaying Current User

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Java Spring Boot and am developing a basic Web App. The two Entity Tables at hand are "Records" and "Users". Users create Records in the App. For the Records table, I want to set a "createdBy" column value based on the current User's email who is signed in. Let's say I have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Records")
public class NewRecord {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="recordId")
    private Long recordId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
    @Column(name="dateCreated")
    private Date dateCreated;
    @Size(max=30)
    @Column(name="createdBy")
    private String createdBy;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
@PasswordMatch(message="{register.repeatPassword.mismatch}")
public class SiteUser {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="userId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="email", unique=true)
    @Email(message="{register.email.invalid}")
    @NotBlank(message="{register.email.invalid}")
    private String email;
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to retrieve the "createdBy" value so that I can display the email of whoever creates each record on the home page. Let's say the following down below is the .jsp page where I want to then display the createdBy value once it's set. I believe once I have set createdBy, I can then just use expression language to retrieve/display it. Or maybe I have to create a Service method to retrieve createdBy(?) Any help on how to set createdBy based on the User would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    
    <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Add a new record</div>
            </div>


                <form:form modelAttribute="newRecord">
                
                    <div class="errors"> 
                        <form:errors path="hwDescription"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:textarea path="hwDescription" name="hwDescription" rows="10" cols="50"></form:textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Record" />
                    
                </form:form>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: If you want users to log in to the webapp, you should consider using [Spring Security](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the current logged in user for your site, you will need to enable spring security. I would take a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/.

Once you have security setup, you will have a User inside the security context when they are signed in.

Once you have completed that part, take a look at this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa#spring

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.